# Casting Function Return Type Based on Class Field

Tags: java, class, object, generics, casting

I've got a class that looks something like.

```
public class ParseValue {
  public String value;
  public final Class classType;
}
```

And I'd like to make a function that does a conversion and returns a casted value.

```
public T parseValue(ParseValue parseInfo) {
  if(parseInfo.classType == String.class) {
    return parseInfo.value;
  } else if (parseInfo.classType == Double.class) {
    return Double.valueOf(parseInfo.value);
  }
}
```

Right now I can have this function return an Object and then cast it upon getting the result, but is there a way to make the function do the cast based on the input ParseValue's classType field?

Comment: Yes. But you'd need to make `ParseValue` generic and the `Class` field as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way to do it is to make `ParseValue` generic:

```
public class ParseValue<T> {
    public String value;
    public final Class<T> classType;

    public T parseValue() {
        Object result;
        if (classType == String.class) {
            result = value;
        } else if (classType == Double.class) {
            result = Double.valueOf(value);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("unknown value type");
        }
        return classType.cast(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: As something of an additional question how would I set that "classType" field?

Comment: From the constructor, presumably.

Comment: public ParseField() {
    this.classType = T.class;
  }

Seems to throw the error "cannot select from a type variable".

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but that's not valid code.

Comment: Sorry, keep hitting enter when I want a line break and that submits the comment prematurely :(.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. You'll have to pass in the type explicitly, e.g., `new ParseValue<Double>("123", Double.class)`.